# Why am I getting [mount error(22): Invalid argument] while trying to mount SMB network drive?

Tags: mount, samba

Disclaimer:  I am very new to Linux :)

Anyway, onward:

I have a fresh instance of Ubuntu Server (12.04.1 LTS) running on my network and I want to mount a network drive to the server so I can access the contents.  The network drive is a SAMBA compatible drive running Darwin OS.

If I run the following command:

`smbclient -L //192.168.0.2 -U myuser`

It prompts me for the password and then displays output similar to:

```
Domain=[SERVER01] OS=[Darwin] Server=[@(#)PROGRAM:smbd  PROJECT:smbx-105.4.0]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
Comp Staff's Public Folder Disk
CompRaid03      Disk
Dropbox         Disk
Groups          Disk
IPC$            IPC
Public          Disk
Users           Disk
compstaff       Disk
```

However, when I try and mount the CompRaid03 share, using this command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/CompRaid03 /mnt/myshare -o username=myuser
```

I get the same password prompt, but after putting the correct password in, I received this error:

`mount error(22): Invalid argument`

dmesg | tail returns:

`[23576.037373] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22`

I don't understand what is wrong with this command.  I've managed to mount a share on my current (Windows 8) machine using basically the same command but with a different IP address and share name (obviously).  I've spent a good few hours trying to solve this and got no where. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Steve

EDIT

As suggested I've also trued using "user=" instead of "username=":

`sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.2/CompRaid03 /mnt/svnrepo -o user=myuser`

This results in the same "Invalid argument" error.

EDIT 2

I feel I should add to the question that in the end I couldn't figure out what the problem was, but, I used the exact same command to mount a share on a different shared drive that was running Debian and it worked fine - I can only assume it's therefore a flaw or idiosyncrasy of the SAMBA implementation that Darwin OS is using.

Comment: I think it is `user=myuser`, not username=myuser See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html

Comment: My only other advice is to put the user before the mount ` sudo mount -t cifs -o user=myuser //192.168.0.2/CompRaid03 /mnt/svnrepo ` , although I am not sure why order would matter.

Comment: Could you test [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13031090/1062019)? It suggests installing `cifs-utils`.

Answer (score 3):

0 down vote

I have found a solution. Add the option sec=ntlm - this works both in a manual mount and from fstab

The fstab entry is now -
Network USB Drive - ie the USB Flash Drive connected to the Modem

//192.168.0.1/USB /home/user/USB cifs sec=ntlm,uid=1000,gid=1000,guest,_netdev 0 0

Based with Thanks from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139090

Answer (score 2):

On RHEL I had to edit file /etc/request-key.conf and add these 2 rows at the end of the file.

```
create       cifs.spnego    * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k
create       dns_resolver   * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason: system can't resolve server name.
I got below error when mounting shared folder.

> ```
> #sudo mount -a
> mount error(22): Invalid argument
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
> ```
>
> /var/log/kern.log:
>   [image]

Edit /etc/resolv.conf, add `search "server"`, issue solved.
[image]